# how this code implements a delay

Tags: keil

```
while（1）
{
  while （x!=5);
  x=0;
  y0=1.5*y1-y2;
  DAC->DHR12R1 (uint16_t)(y0*4095/3.3+2048);
  y2=y1;
  y1=y0;
}
```

I am developing DAC part on keil. how this code implements a delay?

Comment: How can I calculate the value of the delay?  The system core clock runs at 72 MHz

Comment: Does the source from which you got the code explain it?